# How can I bound a type parameter for Tuples without relying on Product?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to declare a function with a type parameter that I want to bound so that only instances of `TupleN` are accepted. However, I don't want to bound on `Product` as instances of case classes, for example, should not be accepted. For instance, if the function is named `foo`:

```scala
case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)
foo(Foo(1, "str")) // should not compile
foo((1, "str"))    // should compile
```

I can achieve this by enumerating all `TupleN` instances for a custom type class and then using a context bound on the type parameter, but I'd prefer to avoid it.

Is it possible to do that in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's the right way to do it. You could do it using a macro, but it wouldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with depending on [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), you can rely on the `IsTuple` type class to provide evidence that a given type is a Scala tuple:

```scala
import shapeless._

def foo[A: IsTuple](v: A) = ???
foo((1, "str")) // compiles
foo(Foo(1, "str")) // does not compile due to lack of evidence
```